# Laravel 5.5 - Deep Relations calling by -->

Tags: laravel-5, model, entity-relationship, laravel-blade, eloquent

I now spent hours googling and experimenting on trying to get an relation with two intermediate tables working.
My database looks like this:
(apt_id is apartment_id in real, was shorter to write)
[image: Database drawing]

I have every relation one away setup correctly with belongsTo and and hasMany:
*EXAMPLE FROM House.php*

```
    public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function apartments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Apartment');
}
```

Isn't there a way to access these relations like:

```
$house->apartments->tenants->entries
```

in Blade:

```
@foreach ( $house->apartments->tenants->entries as $entry )
```

, since I want to display all house entries on house.show (Blade View)

The only way it's working is by using a bunch of foreach inside each others... :/ and they define the order...

Using my wanted relation calling produces:

```
Property [tenants] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

displayed on the page.

Greetings,
Pat

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve what you want using the code you posted, because when calling, for example, `$house->apartments` it returns a Collection object. So, it is not dealing with database anymore, that's why you would need to use a bunch of `@foreach`s.

I don't know if this is the best way to solve this, or if it will help you in your actual problem, but you could think this problem backwards and try something like this:

```
$entries = \App\Entry::whereHas('tenants', function($q) use ($house) {
            $q->whereHas('apartments', function($q1) use ($house) {
                $q1->where('apartments.house_id', $house->id);
            });
        })->get();
```

And in the view:

```
@foreach ($entries as $entry) 
    {{ $entry->tenant->apartment->house->name }}
@endforeach
```